# How to apply weights associated with the NIS (National inpatient sample) in R

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I am trying to apply weights given with NIS data using the R package "survey", but I have been unsuccessful. I am fairly new to R and survey commands.

This is what I have tried:

```
# Create the unweighted dataset
d <- read.dta13(path) 

# This produces the correct weighted amount of cases I need.
sum(d$DISCWT) # This produces the correct weighted amount of cases I need.

library(survey)

# Create survey object
dsvy <- svydesign(id = ~ d$HOSP_NIS, strata = ~ d$NIS_STRATUM, weights = ~ d$DISCWT, nest = TRUE, data = d) 
d$count <- 1
svytotal(~d$count, dsvy)
```

However I get the following error after running the survey total:

```
Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1],  : 
 Stratum (1131) has only one PSU at stage 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: search the survey package help docs for `lonely psu`  you likely just need to choose the adjust option

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have specified a design where one of the strata has just a single primary sampling unit.  It's not possible to get an unbiased estimate of variance for a design like that: the contribution of stratum 1131 will end up as 0/0.

As you see, R's default response is to give an error, because a reasonably likely explanation is that the data or the `svydesign` statement is wrong. Sometimes, as here, that's not  what you want, and the global option 'survey.lonely.psu' describes other ways to respond.  You want to set

```
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
```

This and other options are documented at `help(surveyoptions)`